# Does routing in Meteor transfer HTML between server and client?

Tags: meteor, routes, single-page-application

I am a Meteor newbie, and wonder if the following routing definitions transfer HTML between server and client, or manipulate page routing only in client side?

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/news': 'news', // renders template 'news'

  '/about': function() {
    if (Session.get('aboutUs')) {
      return 'aboutUs'; //renders template 'aboutUs'
    } else {
      return 'aboutThem'; //renders template 'aboutThem'
    }
  },

  '*': 'not_found'
});
```

If it's the former, can I say that routing is not the "Meteor way" because of the first [principles of Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sevenprinciples) is

> Data on the Wire. Meteor doesn't send HTML over the network. The server sends data and lets the client render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a Meteor newbie, and wonder if the following routing definitions
>   transfer HTML between server and client, or manipulate page routing
>   only in client side?

It's actually the latter that is correct, all the application views are transferred initially so client-side routing is just rendering the appropriate templates according to the current URL, no additionnal HTTP requests are performed to fetch server-side rendered HTML as it's the case in traditional LAMP (or any other SSR based stack) websites.