# In Meteor, what does "data on the wire" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

In short: What does "data on the wire" mean. How is it different from HTML being sent? What is happening when a server is not sending HTML?

> Meteor uses data on the wire, meaning the server sends data, not HTML, and the client renders it. - https://guide.meteor.com/

I looked at this - [Does routing in Meteor transfer HTML between server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246524/does-routing-in-meteor-transfer-html-between-server-and-client) - and over there the answerer wrote:

> "all the application views are transferred initially so client-side routing is just rendering the appropriate templates according to the current URL, no additionnal HTTP requests are performed to fetch server-side rendered HTML as it's the case in traditional LAMP (or any other SSR based stack) websites"

Then my question is if a view is sent over isn't that HTML?

My hypothesis is that (in crude terms, I'm not that knowledgable yet):

Usually if I request a resource using a URL, the server finds the appropriate file(s) and sends that HTML over to the client.

With "data on the wire" the server already sent all the files over. And when you submit a request with a URL, client side data that came from the server once in the beginning already knows what to do with the URL, to assemble a piece of HTML for you to look at.

Anything that will help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd guess the difference is whether the template is applied to the data (forming the HTML) on the client or on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data on the wire refers mostly to the way that Meteor forms a websocket connection to the server on page load and then transfers the data needed over that connection.

The websocket is a live connection and as the data changes, the updates are automatically pushed over the wire and the client updates in real time.
(Similar to how many people can edit the same document simultaneously in Google Docs and see each others changes in real time)

This is done using publications and subscriptions. Once a client has subscribed to a data source, the server will send all documents that match the publications. The server will then watch that source for changes and send any new matching documents, updates to, or deletions of existing documents to the client

You are almost right in saying that the HTML is sent in the initial request. Meteor is designed to run using client side rendering frameworks like React, Vue, Angular and Blaze, though it can do static HTML as well. For client side rendering frameworks, Meteor will send an almost empty HTML document and a javascript bundle with the information on how to request the required data and construct the rest of the HTML based on the data returned